# Recalling a method

Tags: ruby, shoes

I wrote a program with three methods: def calculate, def compute, and def capture. Each method had some calculations in them. I want to get just the numeric answer of these methods and use them as a response to a question. I'm looking for it to say something like:
Correct, 'calculate answer' and 'compute answer' and 'capture answer'. How would I do about doing this?

Comment: Oh.. ehmm. It's not clear what you really want

Comment: Edit the question . . . right now you can't understand much from it.

Comment: Are you talking about memoization?

Comment: From the Shoes tag, I think he's asking how to make a graphical interface on top of these methods.

Comment: dmonroe4919, your previous question seems to have been deleted, which is a bit of a shame as I managed to get your app working (http://gist.github.com/339896). I suggest you drop by the Shoes mailing list (shoes@librelist.com).

Comment: I believe my question is clear, I gave a valid description of what I am askinh. I said I was defining a method (i.e. def calculate) that does some calculations within itself i.e. (square root). This calculation gives a numeric value (i.e. 5). I want to take the numeric value and use it again as a form of an equation (i.e. Correct, equation is 5.....).

Comment: I'm sure you understand what you're asking and believe it's clear, but the problem is that nobody else has the slightest idea what you want us to do. OK, you want to take a numeric value and use it as a "form of an equation" (whatever that means). So…go on and do it. I don't know what more information you want from us based on what you've said so far.

Comment: "whatever that means" sums it up nicely. or ... unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at it. Do you mean something like this?

Example code:

```
def calculate a
  a + 4
end

def compute a
  a * 2
end

def capture a
  a - 5
end

def question a
  puts "Correct, 'calculate #{calculate a}' and 'compute #{compute a}' and 'capture #{capture a}'"
end
```

Which, in irb gives:

```
>> question 17
Correct, 'calculate 21' and 'compute 34' and 'capture 12'
=> nil
```